# Facebook Policy on Running Canvas App Outside iFrame?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-canvas

I am currently working on a Facebook app. At the moment it is running in the canvas iFrame. However, ideally I would like it to also be accessible outside of the iFrame as well - much like Branchout is accessible within Facebook and also independent when loaded directly on their website.

According to the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and onto an external site.

Is anyone aware of any additional policies around this?